# Create a dynamic element inside of another dynamic element with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Imagine there is an array with photos, and we want to create a list that shows all of them:

```
photoOptions = ["Blue.jpg", "Red.jpg", "Green.jpg"]
```

Here's the code that I have currently:

```js
photoOptions = ["Red.jpg", "Blue.jpg", "Green.jpg"]
var thumbnailList = document.getElementById('product-options');
var elem = document.createElement("img");
var listItem = document.createElement("li").appendChild(elem)
var clone;
photoOptions.forEach(function(item, index) {
  elem.src = 'http://placehold.it/100?text=' + index;
  clone = listItem.cloneNode();
  thumbnailList.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```html
<ul id="product-options"></ul>
```

It creates the `ul` I want, but instead of the `<img>`'s living inside of an `<li>`, they are just listed as `<img>` elements with no parent `<li>`. What can I do to make the code return a `<ul>` with `<li>`'s that each contain a `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your `var listItem` is being set to the return value of `appendChild`, not to the `li` element.  Also, you need to deep clone in order to copy your image element as well.

```js
photoOptions = ["Red.jpg", "Blue.jpg", "Green.jpg"]
var thumbnailList = document.getElementById('product-options');
var elem = document.createElement("img");
var listItem = document.createElement("li");
listItem.appendChild(elem)
var clone;
photoOptions.forEach(function(item, index) {
  elem.src = 'http://placehold.it/100?text=' + index;
  clone = listItem.cloneNode(true);
  thumbnailList.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```html
<ul id="product-options"></ul>
```

Also, it looks like placehold.it doesn't like `text=0`, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

The answer has to do with object references. Let me explain what the code is doing:

```
var listItem = document.createElement("li").appendChild(elem)
```

The right-hand expression here evaluates to the IMG element. Because the "equals" assignment operator assigns the value of the expression `document.createElement("li").appendChild(elem)` to `listItem`. The expression evaluates the `createElement` method, then the `appendChild` method, and "returns" that last method's return value.

According to MDN's [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) spec, "The returned value is the appended child." So, after this line, `listItem` points to the IMG element.

```
  clone = listItem.cloneNode();
  thumbnailList.appendChild(clone);
```

Then, here, the IMG element is cloned and added to the UL.

---

## Solution:

Make `listItem` reference the LI instead of the IMG:

```
var listItem = document.createElement("li");
listItem.appendChild(elem);
```

This code results in `listItem` pointing to the LI element, and also an IMG is appended to the LI without returning itself to `listItem`.

Comment: P.S. Debugging your code with breakpoints would have shown you this error super quickly.